# Averages based on elements from other columns

Tags: r, dataframe

So, I’ve been trying to get this working but for some reason, I’m just not making any progress on this. And I was hoping if you guys could help me. Pretty much, I have a data frame that I would like to get the average of a specific range of values, where these values are from other columns within the same data frame, for each user.

So, let’s say I have this data frame.

```
a<-data.frame(user=c(rep(1,10),rep(2,10),rep(3,10)),
values=c(1:30),toot=c(rep(4,10),rep(5,10),rep(3,10)))

user    values  toot
    1       1       4
    1       2       4
    1       3       4
    1       4       4
    1       5       4
    1       6       4
    1       7       4
    1       8       4
    1       9       4
    1       10      4
    2       11      5
    2       12      5
    2       13      5
    2       14      5
    2       15      5
    2       16      5
    2       17      5
    2       18      5
    2       19      5
    2       20      5
    3       21      3
    3       22      3
    3       23      3
    3       24      3
    3       25      3
    3       26      3
    3       27      3
    3       28      3
    3       29      3
    3       30      3
```

So, what I would like is to take the average of the values between 2 elements prior of the toot element through the toot element.

Here's what I'm looking for:

```
user    values  toot        deck
    1       1       4       3
    1       2       4       3
    1       3       4       3
    1       4       4       3
    1       5       4       3
    1       6       4       3
    1       7       4       3
    1       8       4       3
    1       9       4       3
    1       10      4       3
    2       11      5       14
    2       12      5       14
    2       13      5       14
    2       14      5       14
    2       15      5       14
    2       16      5       14
    2       17      5       14
    2       18      5       14
    2       19      5       14
    2       20      5       14
    3       21      3       22
    3       22      3       22
    3       23      3       22
    3       24      3       22
    3       25      3       22
    3       26      3       22
    3       27      3       22
    3       28      3       22
    3       29      3       22
    3       30      3       22
```

As you see, for user 1, that user’s toot value is 4, so I want to take the average of user’s 1 values at the 4th element and average it with the 2 elements before it.

This is what I have so far (with many variations of this and with the by function):

```
a$deck<-ave(a$values,a$user,FUN=function(x)
{
  z<-a$toot
  y<-z-2
mean(x[y:z])
})
```

But the problem is that it’s not using the toot value as it’s starting position. Here are the warning messages:

```
> Warning messages:
1: In y:z : numerical expression has 30 elements: only the first used
2: In y:z : numerical expression has 30 elements: only the first used
Error in mean(x[y:z]) : 
error in evaluating the argument 'x' in selecting a method for function 'mean': Error in x[y:z] : only 0's may be mixed with negative subscripts
```

Anything is welcomed and appreciated, thanks.

Comment: The warning is coming because `a$toot` is not a scalar. I cannot get it to work even when using `a$toot[1]`, but that's just because `ave` is a foreign function to me. I've seen `by` (in @Rcoster's solution) more often.

Comment: I remember trying that (a$toot[1]), that works for the first user, but it's going to apply that same value to other users as well. So the first toot value will be applied to all users, which I can't have because each user has a different toot value to start from. 

Thanks for debugging the problem, too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
library(plyr)
ddply(a,.(user),function(df) {
       df$deck <- mean(df$values[(df$toot[1]-2):df$toot[1]]) 
       df
})
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do it with `by()`. Like:

```
do.call(rbind, by(a, a$user, function(x) { cbind(x,deck=mean(x$values[x$toot[1]:(x$toot[1]-2)])) }))
```